# Iterate through ruby database starting from the end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Right now I'm looping through records in a ruby/rails database, making API calls.

My code is:

```
Item.find_each(start: 0, batch_size: 5000) do |item|

response = request(params)

end
```

However, I want to start a second thread to accelerate the process, but have that second thread start from the end of the table, and work backwards.

Is there an out of the box way to do this?

Comment: why not do the same from 2500 to 5000?

Comment: You could start the thread _inside_ the `find_each` block, this way you'll have a thread for each batch - this should accelerate your process...

Comment: Uri - do you mean a second `find_each` inside the `find_each` ?

Comment: @Ryo - the API is rate limited to 1 call per second, and this process is taking a very long time (days).  Sometimes the socket disconnects intermittently.  If one of the processes crashes, while one continues to run, at least I know I'll still have all my data.

Comment: I would suggest you to describe all in more details. How you're connecting to, where from and where to, is it your API or external one and what socket is disconnecting? Describe big picture, how the process works and where's the problem. I'll be much easier to help you then.

Answer (score 0):

Probably if you don't have much control over the api nor the api document provides the way to do what you want, it's impossible.

And if I understood your situation correctly, the best thing you could do is to split data into multiple blocks and run the processes (or threads or whatever suits in your situation) for each of them that are responsible reading it. And decide, into how many blocks you should divide the data considering your constraints (e.g. allowed number of requests per second, the possibility that each request fails, how quickly you can know that a process is hanging or not working etc).

e.g.

If you run 500 processes that each of them are responsible for reading just 10 records, you'll be able to avoid the situation that all the process are hanging, while this will take 500 secs to run all of them.